# A GMP calculator gets stuck with powers

Tags: c, calculator, gmp

I've just written the code for a gmp calculator. Addition and multiplication work impeccably, but as far as exponentiation is concerned it either stops or prints infinite number of zeros.

How to use the gmp power function to make it work?

**gmptest.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>          
#include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mpf_t x1;
    mpf_t x2;
    mpf_t result;
    char operation;
    char x_1[20];
    char x_2[20];
    printf("Choose between *,+ and ^\n");
    scanf("%c\n", &operation);

    fgets(x_1, sizeof(x_1), stdin);
    fgets(x_2, sizeof(x_2), stdin);

    mpf_init(x1);
    mpf_init(x2);
    mpf_init(result);
    mpf_set_str(x1, x_1, 10);
    mpf_set_str(x2, x_2, 10);

    switch(operation) {
    case '+':
        mpf_add(result, x1, x2);
        break;
    case '^':
        mpf_pow_ui(result, x1, x2);
        break;
    case '*':
        mpf_mul(result, x1, x2);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error! operator is not correct");
        break;
    }

    gmp_printf("%0.20Ff", x1);
    printf(" %c ", operation);
    gmp_printf("%0.20Ff", x2);
    gmp_printf(" = %0.20Ff\n\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn compiler warnings on, and pay attention to them. Also read the documentation for functions you are using.  What does _ui stand for in your function name?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `mpf_pow_ui()` is

```
void mpf_pow_ui (mpf_t rop, const mpf_t op1, unsigned long int op2)
```

If you want a floating point exponent, use the [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) library, which works on top of GMP.